# Application state to record time spent using application asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Ok, I have an application and I want to record how long the user spent using the application. At the moment I'm recording everything using session and cookies etc. But how do I start a timer without display it and then end it when the user presses a button to say they're finished. Here's some code. Thanks!

```
// get the time spent
        DateTime timeSpent = Convert.ToDateTime(Application["timeSpent"])
```

---

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application["timeSpent"] = 0;

    }
```

How do I trigger this timer without the user knowing about it etc. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried google analytics?

Comment: Could I use a dispatchertimer? Where would I use it? etc.. thanks!

Comment: No, I have not, sorry!